# Unable to get query parameter from Azure AD B2C login url

Tags: javascript, azure, .net-core, browser, azure-ad-b2c

I have a requirement to add a parameter while using Azure AD B2C login in my application.
I am able to set a parameter in a below method

```
public Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context)
{
   ...
   context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("AppName","MyApp");
}
```

And, it is generating the URL properly like below by adding AppName in URL.

```
https://myazureadb2c.b2clogin.com/myazureaadb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=dddsdsdsdsd&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%564%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openfile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637611242873.MTA4ODdkNAtY2NkMTdkMWYwZWI3&domain_hint=na&AppName=MyApp&state=CfDJ8ZpLR-GP&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0
```

Now, I want to get that parameter value in the custom Azure AD B2C login page and put it on the page.
I am using JavaScript to get parameters from the window.location but when trying to call that function on page load, it is showing, JavaScript is blocked, but it is not(tried in all browsers and same results).

```
<div id="no_js" ><div class="error_container"><div><h1>We can't sign you in</h1><p>Your browser is currently set to block JavaScript. You need to allow JavaScript to use this service.</p><p>To learn how to allow JavaScript or to find out whether your browser supports JavaScript, check the online help in your web browser.</p></div></div></div>
```

Any idea, how can I get that parameter and put it on the custom login page to show the AppName?

Appreciate inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just custom layout without custom policy, you have to enable JavaScript by going to the flow's properties and explicitly enabling JavaScript ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow#begin-setting-up-a-page-layout-version)). If you are using custom policy, you have to make the change in the Identity Experience Framework (IEF) by adding following ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#enable-javascript)):

```xml
<RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <UserJourneyBehaviors>
    <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
  </UserJourneyBehaviors>
  ...
</RelyingParty>
```